# What sigma algebra are we using when considering the sum of two random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

If we consider random variables $X,Y$ both with the sigma algebra $F$, is $Z=X+Y$ defined on the sigma algebra $Z \times Z$ or on $Z$?  In other words, if $X(x)$ is a function of x and $Y(y)$ is a function of y, is $Z$ a function of x and y or just one variable?  Thanks.

Comment: (I assume you meant $F \times F$ rather than $Z \times Z$). Usually a random variable is defined as a function from the sample space $\Omega$ to $\mathbb R$ (or possibly to some other set, and there are some further constraints), so the sum of random variables is just the pointwise sum of these two functions: we have $X + Y: \Omega \to \mathbb R$ and $(X + Y)(\omega) = X(\omega) + Y(\omega)$.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Indeed, one may have trouble defining $X+Y$ if they are not defined on the same probability space :-)